# Ошибка при установке PyQt5-tools

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
E:\Documents>pip install pyqt5-tools
Collecting pyqt5-tools
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.4
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'E:\Programs\Python310\python.exe' 'E:\Programs\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\boro8\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyfq4ed57'
         cwd: C:\Users\boro8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vlfwy0_z\pyqt5_04e5fdf2bc51467d894a587e43c117d9
    Complete output (29 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\Programs\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 143, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\Programs\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
        main()
      File "E:\Programs\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 331, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "E:\Programs\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 147, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\boro8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_f6avdh1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "C:\Users\boro8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_f6avdh1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "C:\Users\boro8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_f6avdh1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 594, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\boro8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vlfwy0_z\pyqt5_04e5fdf2bc51467d894a587e43c117d9\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\boro8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_f6avdh1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\boro8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_f6avdh1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 241, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "C:\Users\boro8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_f6avdh1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
        raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
    sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/a4/d5e4bf99dd50134c88b95e926d7b81aad2473b47fde5e3e4eac2c69a8942/PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz#sha256=2a69597e0dd11caabe75fae133feca66387819fc9bc050f547e5551bce97e5be (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'E:\Programs\Python310\python.exe' 'E:\Programs\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\boro8\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyfq4ed57' Check the logs for full command output
```

Ошибка при скачивании pyqt5-tools. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была такая же проблема.
На странице проекта последняя версия Python 3.9
https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/
Мне помогло просто откатиться на эту версию